# Android RuntimeException

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton mTrueButton;
    private ImageButton mFalseButton;
    private ImageButton mNextButton;
    private ImageButton mPreviousButton;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNextButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mCurrentIndex != 29) {
                    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                    updateQuestion();
                }

            }
        });
        updateQuestion();

        mPreviousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
        mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                try{
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
                if (mCurrentIndex < 0)
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    mCurrentIndex = 0;
                    updateQuestion();
                }

            }
        });
        updateQuestion();

        mTrueButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonTrue);

        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });


        mFalseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFalse);

        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> LOG-CAT:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.Button
>
> > Не понимаю почему, все переменные сделаны ImageButton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.example.artek.stringconstant.MainActivity"
    android:background="#a82f2f">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="164dp"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.36"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#6f6f6f" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/previous_button"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.52">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonTrue"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:src="@drawable/true_button_press"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/true_button"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonFalse"
            android:src="@drawable/false_button_press"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/false_button"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Пишет, что ошибка на пустой строке. Бред какой-то

Comment: Добавьте разметку в вопрос. и строку на коей ошибка тоже обозначьте.

Comment: Ошибка на пустой строке?... 0_о Попробуйте почистить проект (build=>Clean), перезапустить IDE...

Comment: [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28875474/3212712) пишут, что может проблема быть в Eclipse. Решение - удалить разметку и создать её снова с той же разметкой. Т.е. скопипастить.

Comment: Android Studio я использую

Comment: А библиотека поддержки (AppCompat) у вас какой версии? Если 23.2.0, то попробуйте её на 23.1.1 сменить. Последняя версия сей либы содержит баги.

Comment: Я уже не прогаю, но завтра отпишусь. Спасибо :)